# Сбор мыла на сайте ответы маил ру

Tags: python

```
import urllib
import os
import re
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import time

usedEmails = []
num = 0

while True:
    u = urllib.urlopen("http://otvet.mail.ru/")
    page = u.read()

    emailPattern = r"[0-9a-zA-Z_\-\.]+@[0-9a-z-A-Z\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"
    compliedpattern = re.compile(emailPattern)

    for address in compliedpattern.findall(page):
        if not address in usedEmails:
```

Как сделать, чтобы он собирал мыло в простой текстовый документ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот скрипт, проходит все категории и все страницы...Вчера тоже эту статью из хакера прочитал, решил с питоном ознакомиться, вот дополнил к уже существующему...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib
import re

f = open('mails.txt','ab')

url = 'http://otvet.mail.ru'
u = urllib.urlopen(url)
page = u.read()
urlPattern = r'<li><a href="(.*?)"  title="'
urls = re.findall(r'<li><a href="(.*?)"  title="',page, re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
for (categoryUrl) in urls:

    x = 1
    while x <= 50:
        url = "http://otvet.mail.ru" + categoryUrl + "open/?pg=" + str(x)
        print(url)
        u = urllib.urlopen(url)
        page = u.read()
        emailPattern = "[0-9a-zA-Z_\-\.]+@[0-9a-z-A-Z\.]+ru"
        compiledPattern = re.compile(emailPattern)
        unic = uniq = list(set(compiledPattern.findall(page)))
        unic.remove("--Rating@Mail.ru")
        unic.remove("Rating@Mail.ru")
        x += 1

        for (address) in unic:
            print(address)
            f.write(address + '\r\n')
f.close
```

Одна строка явно лишняя, ищи сам.

Answer (score 0):

*не шарю в питоне*

Перед циклом (`for address in ...`) открывать файл на запись

Соответственно, как раз в конце вашего кода записывать в него адрес + `"\n"`.

Погугление дало примерно такое:

```
f = open(r'addr.txt', 'w')
for address in compliedpattern.findall(page):
  if not address in usedEmails:
    f.write(address . "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: пишет что имя urlopen ненайдено
что делать?